# Why is $L^{1}(G)$ unital if and only if $G$ is discrete?

Tags: locally-compact-groups

I've seen it stated in several sources and lecture notes for Abstract Harmonic Analysis that for a locally compact group $G$, $L^{1}(G)$ is unital if and only if $G$ is discrete.

---

What about the locally compact group $\mathbb{T} = \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: |\lambda| = 1\}$, which is not discrete because the arclength measure of a point on the unit circle is $0$.

But since it is compact, the constant function $1\in L^{1}(G)$.

Comment: But the multiplication in $L^1$ is not pointwise multiplication (the pointwise product is generally not in $L^1$), but convolution. The unit for convolution is the Dirac measure in the unit of $G$.

Comment: Thank you! Is that the map $\delta_{1} = \chi_{\{1\}}$?

Comment: If $G$ is discrete, it is represented by $\chi_{\{1\}}$, otherwise, you can't represent it by a function, since it's not absolutely continuous wrt the Haar measure.

Comment: Where Can I get a proof for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplication in the algebra $L^1(G)$ is convolution, not the pointwise product. For groups like $\mathbb{T}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$, the pointwise product of $L^1$ functions is generally not in $L^1$.

You can extend the convolution to the space of Borel measures of bounded variation, and then you get a unital algebra, where the unit is the Dirac measure (point mass) in the unit of $G$. You can represent a point mass as an $L^1$ function with respect to the Haar measure only if singletons have positive measure. That is the case only if $G$ is discrete.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about why isn't a point mass isn't an $L^1$ function? It seems measurable, since the pre-image of {0}, {1} are both measurable (albeit the latter with 0 measure) and the integral would evaluate to 0 (0 * measure of domain w value 0 = 0*1, plus 1 * measure of domain w value 1 = 1*0), hence is finite?

Comment: Oh wait, is the issue that L^1 isn't all the integrable functions, but rather equivalence classes of integrable functions, and the point mass function when points don't have measure is equivalent to 0?

Comment: If $G$ is not discrete, then the point mass $\delta_e\not\in L^1(G)$, but one would still have to show that there is no other possible unit of $L^1(G)$ (which is not a unit of $M(G)$).